# Print a word and numbers lines pattern in python

Tags: python, line

I have two lists,

```py
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I want to create this pattern:

```py
a
1
2
b 
3
4
c
5
6
d
7
8
e
9
10
```

Any ideas about the code?

I have tried this but doesn't get my desired result:

```py
j = 0
for i in range(len((B))):
    if i%2 == 0:
        print(A[j])
    else:
        print(B[i])
    j += 1
```

This is the current output:

```py
a
2
c
4
e
6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Okay, what does it output? Can you guess why?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` with `zip()` to get the desired output:

```py
list(chain.from_iterable(tup for tup in zip(A, B[::2], B[1::2])))
```

This outputs:

```py
['a', 1, 2, 'b', 3, 4, 'c', 5, 6, 'd', 7, 8, 'e', 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterative approach to print the desired output:

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for i in range(len(B)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(A[i // 2]) # get A item at index as twice less than B index
    print(B[i])
```

---

```
a
1
2
b
3
4
c
5
6
d
7
8
e
9
10
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple `range`:

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for i in range(len(A)):
    print(A[i])
    print(B[2*i])
    print(B[2*i+1])
    # or
    # print(A[i], B[2*i], B[2*i+1], sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
a
1
2
b
3
4
c
5
6
d
7
8
e
9
10
```

Variant as a list comprehension:

```
out = [x for i in range(len(A)) for x in (A[i], *B[2*i:2*i+2])]
```

Output:

```
['a', 1, 2, 'b', 3, 4, 'c', 5, 6, 'd', 7, 8, 'e', 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

for `enumerate()` example :

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

result = []

for i, x in enumerate(A):
    result.append(x)
    result.append(B[i*2])
    result.append(B[i*2+1])

print(result)
```

Comment: This won't give the expected output

Comment: It gives the expected output, I wrote the code, tested it, made sure I got the expected answer, and wrote an answer. @mozway

Comment: The expected output is a12b34... not a12b23...

Comment: [image1](https://imgyukle.com/f/2022/12/26/Jzycqq.png) [image2](https://imgyukle.com/f/2022/12/26/JzysGv.png)      you can look here

Comment: Check again, it's not what OP requested ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to remove items from the list as you print them, you can do it this way:

```
while A:
    print(A.pop(0))
    print(B.pop(0))
    print(B.pop(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be so fast using generators lazy loading
and hyperparamter `N` you can manupliate as data change anytime.

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
N = 2
for i in zip(A, (B[i:i+N] for i in range(0, len(B), N))):
    print(i[0])
    print(i[1][0])
    print(i[1][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

While all answers are correct some extent, Below is tested code for first edit of the question

```
res=[]
final_out = ''
for i in range(len(A)):
    res.append(A[i]+str(B[2*i])+str(B[2*i+1]))
for j in res:
    final_out = final_out+j
print(final_out)
```

```
a12b34c56d78e910
```